# Check if subview exists in swift 1.2

Tags: swift

I have added my subview using

```
self.view.addSubview(noticeSubView)
```

At some point I need to check if that subview exists before proceeding with some other actions etc. I found the following while searching but not sure if it is how it is done and also how to implement.

```
BOOL doesContain = [self.view.subviews containsObject:pageShadowView];
```

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: isDescendantOfView() ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Rather than asking if a subview exists in your view, you are better off asking if the subview (in your case noticeSubView) has a parent that is your view.

So in your example you would check later for:

```
if ( noticeSubView.superview === self.view ) {
  ...
}
```

The triple "===" is making sure that the superview object is the same object as self.view, instead of trying to call isEqual() on the view.

Another approach people have used in the past is to set an integer tag on a subview, like so:

```
noticeSubView.tag = 4
```

The default is zero so anything nonzero will be unique.

Then you can check to see if a superview contains a specific view by tag:

```
if ( self.view?.viewWithTag(4) != nil )
...
}
```

If you take that approach, you should probably create an enum for the integer value so it's clearer what you are looking for.

Note:  There's a "?" after `self.view` because a view controller will not have a view defined until after `viewDidLoad`, the "?" makes sure the call will not occur if `self.view` returns `.None`

Comment: if ( noticeSubView.superview === self.view ) {
  ...
}

And isDescendentOf both crash. I'm guess its because I never initialized my subviews. But shouldn't it just return nil? I mean the are declared var frontCardView:SwipeChartView!

Comment: It does return nil before viewDIdLoad, which crashes in Swift because the view for a VC is a forced Optional, which means it assumes it's there - dangerous.  Try self.view?.viewWirhTag(4) which will properly return an optional to check against instead of crashing. I'll update my answer.  However, you will have to find somewhere after the view is loaded to put this code if you are seeing self.view not yet set.  Instead of Init, try viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 2):

If `noticeSubView` is a custom class (let's call it `NoticeSubView`), then you can find it like this:

```
for view in self.view.subviews {
    if let noticeSubView = view as? NoticeSubView {
        // Subview exists
    }
}
```

Or, you can assign a tag to the view and search for it.

```
noticeSubView.tag = 99
//...

for view in self.view.subviews {
    if view.tag == 99 {
        // Subview exists
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I like that idea with the custom class 'for view in self.' ... I will need that approach in another controller.

Answer (score -1):

best and easy way to find that your view is exist or not , there are many way like you check a view is contain or not in super view or just view some time this method is failed because if the Uiview is already remove then error occur, so code is here : here errorView is my UiView

```
 errorView.tag = 333

 if ( self.view?.viewWithTag(333) != nil ){
    print("contain")
 }

 else {
    print("not contain")
 }
```

Comment: How is this any different from the second half of the accepted answer?